# Regex for get the path of file

Tags: regex, jtable

I have code to display a name of file to a jtable. Here is the code :

```
StringBuilder nameOfComparedFile = new StringBuilder(); // 

if (idLexerSelection != getIDLexer()) {

  nameOfComparedFile.append(file.getCanonicalPath()); // 
  System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath() + " )");
}
```

And then, in jtable is displayed like this : D:/Data/File.java
I dont wanna change getCanonicalPath, because on jtable that i Created will be using for next process. My question is : how to get just the name of file using regex

Answer (score 0):

To get just the name:

```
file.getName()
```

If you absolutely must use regex:

```
String filename = file.getCanonicalPath().replaceAll(".*[\\\\/](.*)", "$1");
```

Comment: I am interest to using regex

Comment: Well there's the regex version. It will work on all file systems (windows and Linux)